# can connection string in SQL Server 2005 be taken from a file?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, .net-3.5

I have **created a web enabled DB** for a company as a part of my internship and it's up and ready. However the **connection string of the server is already coded by me**. But the IT guy said that he wanted me to **read the connection string from a file** containing various connection strings and choosing whichever it wanted to at that time.

My question is, Is it possible???....If Yes How???

Kindly help me...i had a long session with him trying to understand the concept, still could'nt get it.

Thanking in anticipation
Sujit

Comment: What programming language have you used? How is the connection string used in code?

Comment: What's the environment you're developing in?  .NET?

Comment: @oded and ngroot......it;s .NET framework 3.0 using Visual Studio 2008 and coded in C#

Comment: @oded connection string is specified in web.config

Comment: if he wants you to use something other than web.config/app.config, tell him to show you an example. your organization may have alternate recommended practices.

Comment: @S_anand ... well then you are already done. Just tell the guy the connection string is in the web.config file and they just change it at deployment time. If you have multiple connection strings and need to change dynamically based on some programmatic condition ... well, you write code to check the condition and read the correct connection string setting, as discussed in the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Comment: There is nothing in the question to indicate .NET

Comment: OP has commented that it is.  It was a safe bet anyways.

Comment: he has now... but it is not certain. I do agree that if he is using SQL-Server, he is probably using an MS language, but it might have been unmanaged C++ :)

Comment: @Oded: the likelihood of a student coding a website in c++ is pretty slim.  Also, the likelihood of a student using anything other than a .net language to tie to a MS SQL backend is equally slim.

Comment: @Chris Lively - All I am saying is that there was nothing _definite_ in the question and more info was required.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem.

Put the connection string in a file, read the file in your program and pass the string in to the database connection object you are using.

This is so common that in .NET the configuration file schema already has a place for connection strings (plus mechanisms to encrypt that section).

**Update:**

As you indicate that you are using .NET, you should look into the `app.config` file, in particular the [`ConfigurationMananger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260.aspx) and the [`ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) section/property.